# Android Studio: StringBuilder content not shown in preview of debugger

Tags: android-studio, debugging, kotlin, stringbuilder

I'm implementing an app, which uses (kotlin.text.)StringBuilder instances at various points. Since today, I have to double-click the variable name and, after that, double-click 'value' to see the content shown as one character per line (next to 'value', it also says e.g. char[20]). Until yesterday, I was able to see their contents in the variables view of the debugger right after double-clicking the variable name and - what is even more important - in one single string line. I have to compare the content of several instances and therefore cannot work efficiently with this view.

Is there some kind of setting, which needs to be reset? Has anyone else experienced this? Is this an intended behavior or am I the only one having this bug/behavior?

After getting this, I already tried restarting android studio, as well as upgrading all components to the latest version. I also tried creating an entirely new project with only one StringBuilder to rule out any problems in my current project - but, no luck so far.

Any hint would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution to the problem. It was indeed a setting I had to reset. As I did not actively change it, this solution might be useful to others, too.

Via 'Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data Views > Java', I found the option 'Enable 'toString()' object view:'. After selecting this option, everything worked again as before.

Thanks to everyone, who tried to figure out the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `.toString()` call to your string builder to get the value of the string.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your point, but my productive code works just like before (I'm using toString() to get the content there). Only the variables view within the debugger does not show the content like before.